# No matching function for call to ‘Event<float>::notify(NULL, const double&)’|

Tags: c++, algorithm, events, openframeworks

I am using a framework here for one of my programs and creating an event (from the [example here](http://www.openframeworks.cc/documentation/events/ofEvent.html))

.h file

```
ofEvent<float> onVolumeChange
```

.cpp file

```
//main method()
ofAddListener(onVolumeChange, this, &MainProgram::handleVolumeChange);

//kePrees method
if(key== ' '){
ofNotifyEvent(onVolumeChange, 10.0f);
}
```

I get a compilation error on trying to build this and it seems very strange since I am just following the example that is there already.

The error that I get here is:

`No matching function for call to ‘ofEvent<float>::notify(NULL, const float&)’|`

About my machine if required: Ubuntu 12.04, Codeblocks, C++/openFrameworks

What is that I am missing here?

Comment: check the parameter  ofNotifyEvent(onVolumeChange, `10.0f`); Usually the error happens when parameters passed in method not correct

Comment: Does the error message really say `null` in the first argument? That's pretty strange, it's supposed to show a type there.

Comment: @Mat: Yes, that's what the error says. Even I try to pass `bool` EventArgs, I get the same error of `No matching function for call to ‘ofEvent<float>::notify(NULL, const bool&)’|`

Comment: Problem is the first argument, not the second. The second makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

the MainProgram class should have:

```
void MainProgram::handleVolumeChange(float& variable){
    //handler
}
```